# jquery don't work, with many div's (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Morning Fellows,

I'm working on a Wordpress-Website. I've a jquery script that triggers me a text panel, with a hover/mouseover event.

I don't know why the jquery doesn't work, the script works fine if I add a simple text with the trigger class, but for some reason I cant trigger it with an img or another class element.

First I thought that the css blocks the query, but css is only for the look ? or am I wrong ?

The second question would be, if I can make the jquery run as the html toggle button. I don't want the text shown as overlay, it should move every thing down below, I've tried to replace the slideDown attribute with a toggle attribute but it doesn't work.

Maybe something in wordpress blocks the trigger, 
It would be nice if anyone could help me out!

peace 
john

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".info").hide();
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").slideUp(200);
  });
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").slideDown(200);
  });
});
```

```css
.uk-grid-width-1-4 > * {
  width: 25%;
}
.uk-panel {

  display: block;
 
  position: relative;
}

.uk-panel,
.uk-panel:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.uk-panel:before,
.uk-panel:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.uk-panel:after {
  clear: both;
}

.uk-panel > :not(.uk-panel-title):last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.uk-panel-teaser {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.uk-overlay {
  /* 1 */
  display: inline-block;
  /* 2 */
  position: relative;
  /* 3 */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* 4 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 5 */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* 6 */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  /* 7 */
  margin: 0;
}
.uk-overlay-hover:not(:hover):not(.uk-hover) .uk-overlay-panel:not(.uk-ignore) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.uk-overlay-active :not(.uk-active) > .uk-overlay-panel:not(.uk-ignore) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.uk-position-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.info {
 display:none;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #fff;
 position:relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index:10;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wk-grid51f" class="uk-grid-width-1-4 " data-uk-grid="{gutter: ' 10',controls: '#wk-51f'}" style="position: relative; margin-left: -10px; height: 316px;">

    
    <div data-uk-filter="Gewerbe" data-grid-prepared="true" style="position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
    
<div class="uk-panel">

    <div class="uk-panel-teaser trigger">

        <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover ">

            <img src="223.jpg" alt="blabla" width="1875" height="1250">
            
            
            
                                                                        <a class="uk-position-cover" href="#wk-351f" data-index="0" data-uk-modal=""></a>
                                                
        </figure>

    </div>

    
        
                <div>
<div class="info" style="display: none;"><p> <b> blabla </b> </p>
<p> blabla </p>

<p> <b> blabla</b>
blabla
</p></div>
</div>
        
    
</div>
    </div>

    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.info` element is not the sibling of the selector but selector's parent's sibling element, So, you have to change it with the usage of `.closest()` and `.siblings()` instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".info").hide();
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.uk-panel').siblings(".info").slideUp(200);
  });
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.uk-panel').siblings(".info").slideDown(200);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div that is wrapping `.info`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".info").hide();
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").slideUp(200);
  });
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").slideDown(200);
  });
});
```

```css
.uk-grid-width-1-4 > * {
  width: 25%;
}
.uk-panel {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.uk-panel,
.uk-panel:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.uk-panel:before,
.uk-panel:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.uk-panel:after {
  clear: both;
}
.uk-panel >:not(.uk-panel-title):last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.uk-panel-teaser {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.uk-overlay {
  /* 1 */
  display: inline-block;
  /* 2 */
  position: relative;
  /* 3 */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* 4 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 5 */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* 6 */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  /* 7 */
  margin: 0;
}
.uk-overlay-hover:not(:hover):not(.uk-hover) .uk-overlay-panel:not(.uk-ignore) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.uk-overlay-active:not(.uk-active) > .uk-overlay-panel:not(.uk-ignore) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.uk-position-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.info {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wk-grid51f" class="uk-grid-width-1-4 " data-uk-grid="{gutter: ' 10',controls: '#wk-51f'}" style="position: relative; margin-left: -10px; height: 316px;">


  <div data-uk-filter="Gewerbe" data-grid-prepared="true" style="position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">

    <div class="uk-panel">

      <div class="uk-panel-teaser trigger">

        <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover ">

          <img src="223.jpg" alt="blabla" width="1875" height="1250">



          <a class="uk-position-cover" href="#wk-351f" data-index="0" data-uk-modal=""></a>

        </figure>

      </div>




      <div class="info" style="display: none;">
        <p> <b> blabla </b> 
        </p>
        <p>blabla</p>

        <p> <b> blabla</b>
          blabla
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesnt worked. Something blocks the query to run. I dont think the query not find the info class. I think something from the uk-overlay css is blocking the sricpt from running. I have uesed the widgetkit from yootheme for my grid layout.